# How to create an infinite collection from a Scala Set

Tags: scala

Is there a more elegant method than going through a `Seq`?

```
val origin = Set("a", "b")
val intermediate = origin.toSeq
val stream = Stream.from(0).map { index =>
    intermediate(index % intermediate.size)
}.toIterator

stream.next() // => "a"
stream.next() // => "b"
stream.next() // => "a"
```

I am specifically targeting Scala 2.9.

Comment: This may interest you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097851/scala-repeat-a-finite-list-infinitely

Comment: @AlexisC. why isn't this an answer? It's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097851/scala-repeat-a-finite-list-infinitely).

The easiest way is to use recursive definition:

```
val stream: Stream[String] = origin.toStream #::: stream
```

*#:::* is stream concatenation operator. It is equivalent to:

```
val stream: Stream[String] = origin.toStream.append(stream)
```